# SSMS Create Table Default DataType

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

On the odd occasion I use SSMS to create a table (rather than by script) the default datatype it gives a new field is `nchar(10)` (see img)

[image]

I rarely want an `nchar(10)` so is there a way for me to change this to a default datatype of my choice?

Comment: it takes default nchar(10) but you can also choose from dropdown menu right ? click on datatype then choose from the dropdown ?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi yes I can change it to the datatype I want it would just be handy if I could change the default type to one of my choice.  Begs the question why is nchar(10) the assumed datatype when creating a new field.